# Nginx try files not working

Tags: nginx

I want to serve static content from three folder using nginx, where root is tb:

```
 location ~*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|swf|jsb)$ {
     root E:/tb/;
     try_files $uri/tp1/ $uri/tp2/ $uri/tp3/;
     access_log off;
     expires max;
    }
```

Above configuration is not working for me.

Comment: My guess is the files are not located in e.g. `E:/tb/$uri/tp1` (where $uri should be expanded to wahtever the uri is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put space after `~*` and change `try_files` like this:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|swf|jsb)$ {
  root E:/tb/;
  try_files /tp1$uri /tp2$uri /tp3$uri;
  access_log off;
  expires max;
}
```